# Getting database server IPs from tnsnames.ora

Tags: c#, oracle12c, tnsnames

I am working on a web application that will be deployed on individual app servers, each connecting to a different Oracle DB. DB connections are specified in each app server's tnsnames.ora file.
Also, each tns names entry uses multiple database IP addresses to handle failovers.

```
ABCD = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (FAILOVER = on) 
      (LOAD_BALANCE = off) 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.2.3.4)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.2.3.5)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.2.3.10)(PORT = 1521))
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVICE_NAME = abcd) 
      (FAILOVER_MODE = 
        (TYPE = SELECT) 
        (METHOD = BASIC) 
      ) 
   ) 
)
```

I am trying to find a way to get he IP address of the database that the app server is currently using.

I have searched everywhere but can't find a solution and frankly don't even know if it is doable.

I can execute:

```
netstat -a | findstr ":1521"

TCP    10.20.30.40:52707     Blah1:1521     ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.20.30.40:57022     Blah2:1521     ESTABLISHED
TCP    10.20.30.40:57024     Blah3:1521     ESTABLISHED
```

to find all connections made to port 1521, which is used by Oracle DB. I should then be able to do an nslookup to get the IP address of Blah1, Blah2 and Blah3.

I might have to parse tnsnames.ora file, using the tns entry name used by the app (ABC); then compare IP I get from nslookup to see which one matches.

Is there a built-in way of doing this? Has anyone run into this situation and managed to resolve it?
How can I tell if it is 1.2.3.4 or 1.2.3.5 or 1.2.3.10 that the app is connecting to?

Comment: I'm guessing that the point in having multiple addresses is that each connection to the database would be to whichever address is available at the time. And just because it failed over on one connection doesn't mean that it will fail over on the next one; it could be temporary. If it's possible to answer your question, it would have to be inspected at the `OracleConnection` level for a given active connection, not the application on the whole.

Comment: netstat -o will include the process id.

Comment: I actually tried netstat -a -o -b. Got three entries returned but not sure what to do with PID.

Comment: @madreflection That was another option I was thinking: make a connection to Oracle database and inspect the connection properties and see if it includes DB host name or IP. Not sure if it does but can give it a try.

Comment: @madreflection creating an Oracle connection and opening it and the inspecting its properties was the way to do it, as you suggested. I could see from connection object's HostName property the DB server name, from which I can get the IP address. Please change your comment to answer and I will mark it as such. You can add what I mentioned about getting host name from conn. object. Thanks.

Comment: Ran into a snag: I can get database hostname, and from there its IP address by investigating Oracle connection object. However, what I get is the physical IP address of DB server and what is used in tnsnames.ora (with failover options) are virtual server IPs and those are what I am looking for.